# KieBase from ByteArray Resource

Tags: java, drools, kie

How to build a KieBase from byteArray resource?

```
resource = kService.getResources().newByteArrayResource(drlRuleData).setResourceType(ResourceType.DRL);//The Byte Array is obtained from a DRL file
kFile.write("src/main/resources/simple.drl",resource);
kbuilder = kService.newKieBuilder(kFile);
kContainer = kService.newKieContainer(kbuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId());
kbase= kContainer.getKieBase();
```

The Kbase is not getting constructed properly and my rules are not executed. Please tell where I am wrong and what I should change.

Comment: You don't call the builder. Do that, and make sure to check for errors.

Comment: I have tried adding it also..
kbuilder = kService.newKieBuilder(kFile).buildAll();

I have checked for errors also.. It is throwing me errors when I am trying to add ByteArray

Comment: The byte array which I am using is generated from a drl.. Should I mention the resource type as DRL then ?

Comment: If it is "throwing [...] errors", you'll have to fix them. You know what the message says, I don't.

Comment: Fine Fine.. That I am doing..